# Median filtering - cheating?

Tags: experimental-physics, statistics

The concept is simple, and is used to remove non-typical data. A sample set is put in numerical order and the extremes discarded. For example, in an experiment I am doing I take batches of 10 measurements and discard all but the center 4 results. It improves the reliability (relative standard deviation) of the final results enormously.

How legitimate is this in general in physics? I can certainly imagine situations where doing this by hand would be considered to be falsifying the data.

Comment: That crucially depends on your *justification* for discarding the outliers (obviously "it improves the result" isn't enough).

Comment: Well, the engineering argument is "It Works!". The justification in this experiment is that it removes glitches that are far from the trend line. Of course, over using it creates a trend line...

Comment: You can't say things are "glitches" without saying *why* they are "glitches" and not "data". That things are far from the nice trend line we wanted to see gives us no right to discard data, there must be justification why they are glitches (i.e. we must explain where they come from). As such, this question can't be answered for any general experiment, but crucially depends on the actual setup and the kind of outliers you see, in my opinion.

Comment: True. It seems to be more an engineering thing, for example, removing noise from images. I had never used it before this experimental work I am doing, and it seems amazingly effective for extracting signal from noise. Crucially, I know what the signal is that I am trying to extract. I am not looking for "unknowns" in the data stream.

Answer (score 2):

When you say "improves the reliability", well that is not clear at all, because you have reduced your sample size and possibly introduced an (unknown) bias.

Median filtering is typically used where you do not fully understand the noise properties of your sample and where there may be cases of results that are way out from the expected result because of rare phenomena that cannot be fully characterised. i.e Distinctly non-Gaussian tails in the distribution that might enable you to characterise the distribution in terms of something that is more well behaved plus "outliers".

So an example from astronomy might be the averaging of a number of spectra of the same object, where an occasional pixel in a spectrum may be contaminated by a cosmic ray strike. Such events will lead to a small, but distinctly non-Gaussian tail in the distribution of measured values. Taking the mean in such circumstances, would give crazy values at the positions of pixels affected by the cosmic rays in one of the spectra, so the median is preferred.

The experiment you describe does not sound like that, unless you have a plausible reason why more than half your data are no good. Yes it will extract a signal, but whether that signal could be considered "reliable" is moot in those circumstances. Certainly the standard deviation of the remaining objects would be no indicator of the noise. A better noise estimate would be the [median absolute deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_absolute_deviation) of the whole sample.

Comment: Thanks. I am measuring time of flight, and the glitches tend to be outliers that are multiples of the wavelength because I fail to lock onto the data perfectly every time.

Comment: @DirkBruer Then that is quite a different matter. You have a *systematic error*. This is beginning to sound like the justification CuriousOne talks about. I'd suggest then trying to hatch a simple mathematical model for what your data should look like when you don't lock on (it sounds as though you're talking imperfect fringe counting in interferometry, right?). Then you might be able to come up with a maximum likelihood determination of which results have "fringe slipped". But witness that this will be a culling criterion grounded on the *physics* involved, not a standard recipe.